# Functional Difference between the Distal Promoter and Enhancer Region

Tags: molecular-biology, gene, transcription

According to the Wikipedia article on eukaryotic [promoter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)?wprov=sfti1) regions, the distal promoter is:

> Anything further upstream (but not an enhancer or other regulatory region whose influence is positional/orientation independent)

What is the difference between the regulatory region and the distal promoter? Does the distal promoter region have a greater effect on the rate of transcription?
If so, is the determination for what has a big enough effect to be a distal promoter subjective?